# Finish code folding in one line (and keep folding sign visible all the time)

Tags: visual-studio-code, copy-paste, folding

Code folding in VScode doesn't seem as good as IntelliJ's.

eg. code block

```
def g(a):
    print(a)
    print(a)
    print(a)
    print(a)
    print(a)
```

Or, for (...),{...},[...]  (indentation isn't actually the real concern.)

eg code sample from dart(flutter):

```
OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  SecondPage.id,
                );
              },
              child: Text("Page 2"),
            )
```

1. So, now if I fold this code and try to duplicate the folded line, it doesn't copy the entire fold as it does in IntelliJ. Is there an extension or settings, with which I can achieve the same as IntelliJ? I've found a comment which says I need to copy till the beginning of the next line which is not what I want. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51232#issuecomment-395190470

- If I press Enter after folding, it creates a new line in the folding section, I actually want it to create the line after the folding section.

2. VScode only shows the folding sign when I hover the mouse over it, I want it visible all the time.

Comment: For #2 see the setting `Editor: Show Folding Controls` set to `always`.

Comment: For #1, it seems impossible. There is an issue opened about it, check here, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3352

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the code language is Python.

> So, now if I fold this code and try to duplicate the folded line, it doesn't copy the entire fold as it does in IntelliJ

You need to select the whole region. To do that, simply do a `Shift+Down`, then you can copy/paste the region.

> If I press Enter after folding, it creates a new line in the folding section, I actually want it to create the line after the folding section.

Python's folding regions are based on the indentation. So when pressing `Enter` after a folding, the new line is tabbed so it is inside the region. You need to delete the tab so the line isn't in the region.

> Finish code folding in one line

To fold on a single line, you need to use the extension [Explicit Folding](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zokugun.explicit-folding) and the following configuration:

```
"[python]": {
    "explicitFolding.rules": [
        {
            "beginRegex": "\"\"\"",
            "endRegex": "\"\"\"",
        },
        {
            "indentation": true,
            "offSide": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually finish the folding in one line. But, I appreciate your advice.

Comment: @Cyber Avatar, I think it's moot with your code as it seems that is indentation based not syntax based, but if that's not the case, I second daiyam's Explicit Folding recommendation (note he is that extension's author, so you can work with him to improve it if you want).  I use it to solve Code's most irritating folding issue (folding doesn't consume last line in bracket/tag languages). Takes a bit of configuring sometimes, depending on the need, but when you get it right it works a treat.

Comment: Hmm, I've further added information here, github.com/zokugun/vscode-explicit-folding/discussions/… python indentation is not really the only concern, I've also updated the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Three points.  Two addressed by others already but I'll include them here for completeness, with the third being my own contribution.

1. Fundamentally, Code's philosophy seems to be that the end of the line containing all the folded code seems to be considered the end of the first line of the folded code, not the end of all the folded code.  The folded code exists between the start of the first line of the code in question, and the **start** of the **next visible line** (the first line after the folded section). Therefore:

- As per [daiyam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16373370/daiyam)'s answer, press `Shift+Down` at the start of the folded code to select everything between it and the next visible line. This then includes all the folded code, which you can then copy/paste.
- My own contribution here: Similarly, to add a new line after the folded code, either press `Down` from the start of the folded code line, or press `Right` from the end of that line, to get to the start of the next line.  Then press `Enter` to add a new line there.  Then `Up` to get to the start of the new line.^^

2. As per [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark)'s comment set the `Editor: Show Folding Controls` to `always`.

---

^^ *Some potentially overkill analysis  ...*

*Yes, that seems like a lot of steps for something you're used to doing in one step in IntelliJ, except it's only two extra (arrow) key presses. If you're switching away from IntelliJ, to Code, then your muscle memory will likely adapt pretty quick. That might only be a problem if you're switching back and forth between them frequently.*

*Also, whatever keys or mouse click you've done to get to the start or end of that first folding line in the first place could be replaced by a different click or key presses to get you to the start of that next line instead. So the only extra really is the `Up` key after the `Enter`, plus the (presumably pretty tiny) learning curve to remember to go to that next line start instead of previous line end.*

*I suppose if that's a big deal, you could use any of the Macro applications to combine those extra arrow keystrokes and the `Enter` to one keystroke (say `Shift+Enter` or something). I find myself doing that sort of thing a lot to bring consistency to my use of different IDE's etc.*

*Just a couple of ideas in case they help.*